# What is a reason to have ACCEPT and DROP rule for the same traffic in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I found this in my server's iptables:

```
-A INPUT -i eth2.600 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m limit --limit 10000/sec --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth2.600 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j DROP
```

Will packets be accepted from port 53 or not? Or will they be accepted as long as first rule is ok (the limit is not reached) and then dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action will only be taken if *all* rule conditions match – other packets "fall through" to the next rule. The same applies whether the port doesn't match, or the protocol doesn't match, or the rate-limit doesn't match.

So if the packet satisfies `-m limit` it will be ACCEPTed, but if it doesn't satisfy the limit then **no** action will be takne by the first rule – the packet will just goes down to the second (DROP) rule.

Having an explicit DROP depends on the ruleset – it isn't 100% necessary (e.g. there could be a catch-all DROP in the end, or a global drop policy), but it provides some clarity if the ruleset is very long, and prevents the same packets from being accidentally accepted by another rule below.